# Inverting the Black formula for Cap price to find Black implied volatility

Tags: programming, implied-volatility, calibration, heath-jarrow-morton

I'm solving the following problem as a part of [Interest Rate Models](https://www.coursera.org/learn/interest-rate-models?) class on Coursera

[image: calibration of 1-factor Gaussian HJM]

I'm having a hard time using nonlinear root solver to invert the Black formula for Cap price in order to obtain a Black implied volatility that will be used further for calibration purposes. My Python code is attached below.

```
import numpy as np
import math
import scipy
from scipy import optimize
from scipy import stats

Time = [0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4]
ForwardRates = [0.06, 0.08, 0.09, 0.10, 0.10, 0.10, 0.09, 0.09]
CapPrices = [0.20, 0.80, 1.20, 1.60]
SimpleRates = []
DiscountFactors = []

SimpleRates.append(ForwardRates[0])
DiscountFactors.append(1/(1+Time[0]*SimpleRates[0]))

for i in range(1, len(Time)):
    SimpleRates.append(((1+0.5*ForwardRates[i])*(1+Time[i-1]*SimpleRates[i-1])-1)/Time[i])
    DiscountFactors.append(1/(1+Time[i]*SimpleRates[i]))

SwapRates = []
for k in range(1, len(Time)):
    s = sum(DiscountFactors[i] for i in range(1, k + 1))
    SwapRates.append((DiscountFactors[0] - DiscountFactors[k])/(0.5*s))

def d1(i, sigma):
    return (np.log(ForwardRates[i]/SwapRates[i])+0.5*math.pow(sigma, 2)*Time[i-1])/(sigma*math.sqrt(Time[i-1]))

def d2(i, sigma):
    return (np.log(ForwardRates[i]/SwapRates[i])+math.pow(sigma, 2)*Time[i-1])/(sigma*math.sqrt(Time[i-1])) - sigma*math.sqrt(Time[i-1])

def caplet(begin, end, sigma):
    return 0.5*DiscountFactors[end]*(ForwardRates[end]*scipy.stats.norm.cdf(d1(end, sigma))-SwapRates[end]*scipy.stats.norm.cdf(d2(end, sigma)))

def cap(end, sigma):
    price = 0
    for j in range(1, end + 1):
        price += caplet(j - 1, j, sigma)
    return price

s = scipy.optimize.bisect(lambda sigma: cap(1, sigma) - CapPrices[0], 0.0005, 0.5)
```

I'm getting an error that f(a) and f(b) must have different signs regardless of my interval choice. What particular root solving method should I use in Python to get around that? Is there anything else that I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that cap prices are given as %, therefore your vector of cap prices should be

```
CapPrices = [0.002, 0.008, 0.012, 0.016]
```

while you have

```
CapPrices = [0.20, 0.80, 1.20, 1.60]
```

The code should find solution without problem for these cap prices.

Notice that for your incorrectly given CapPrices there is no solution. Notice:

${Caplet(F,\sigma,t) \to F} $ as $\sigma \to \infty$. Therefore the highest caplet value is $F$, but you are trying to find solution for roughly $2.5F$ i.e. (0.20 / 0.08 = 2.5), therefore the solver fails.

I have also noticed that you have error in your formula in d2, it should be equal to:

```
return (np.log(ForwardRates[i]/SwapRates[i])+0.5*math.pow(sigma, 2)*Time[i-1])/(sigma*math.sqrt(Time[i-1])) - sigma*math.sqrt(Time[i-1])
```

while you have (missing multiplication by 0.5)

```
return (np.log(ForwardRates[i]/SwapRates[i])+math.pow(sigma, 2)*Time[i-1])/(sigma*math.sqrt(Time[i-1])) - sigma*math.sqrt(Time[i-1])
```